# When im running my mono android application cant run the emulator and getting deployment errors

Tags: c#, mono

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;

namespace MoviePlayer
{
    [Activity(Label = "MoviePlayer", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        MediaPlayer mp;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.Prepare();
            mp.SetDataSource("F:\\DCIM\\100MEDIA\\VIDEO0034.3gp");
            mp.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

When im running the application i see a window of Select Device
I see my android there listed but its offline like i cant select it maybe czu um using evaluation version of mono ?

So instead im trying to select Start Emulator Image and there i see two images i created.
Both of 2.2 android
I select one of them double click and nothing happened. Im back to first window where my android is offline in the list.

If i select Cancel im getting error say: There were deployment errors.
If i select not to continue NO its exiting the debug and stop running.
If i select YES to continue im getting error say:

Build Failed

MonoDroid does not support running the previous version. please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.

So i tried to make: Build Solution and Rebuild Solution i didnt got any errors but it didnt solve this deployment errrors message.

In other words how do i run and use the emulator ?! 
I will not buy the program for now its 399$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug is Google's latest Android SDK where the emulator will not start if you installed it to a location that contains spaces (ie: the default).

Uninstall the Android SDK and reinstall it to a place that does not contain spaces, like C:\android.

Comment: I tried as you said jpobst and then i tried to make the Hwllo World code and i can see now the emulator but i dont see the text "hello world" there. and still when i exiting the emulator and the emulator window and stop the debugging/running of the application im getting error " If i select Cancel im getting error say: There were deployment errors. If i select not to continue NO its exiting the debug and stop running. If i select YES to continue the error i mentioned above. im not sure if this error make that i dont see the text in the emulator "hello world"